# How can i fix the margin of a label next to a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I have a check box that I have added a `margin-right:10px` for a little space between them. It's working fine but when the label have a line-break like this [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/218/), the margin doesn't seem to work properly. I would like to have the check box alone on the left and the label on the right without having it under the checkbox if it have multiple lines.

Code

```
<dd id="rr-element">
   <label for="rr-1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
      Value 1 lorem lipsum dolor si amet 
   </label>
</dd>
```

CSS

```
#rr-element{width:180px;}
dd label input {
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

**Little update** : The max-width of the ul or dd is 180px; I don't want it to be on a single line.

Comment: In this case, you don't need to use `for="rr-1"`, you could remove that.

Comment: It's because I have like 20 checkbox, the rr-1 it's based on it's id from rr-1 to rr-20. I need it for the label to be clickable...

Comment: I know, but you're wrapping the input by *label* element. In this case, you don't have to use `for` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

**html**

```
<dd id="rr-element">
    <input value="2" id="rr-1" type="checkbox" name="SearchForm[position][]">
    <label for="rr-1">Value 1 lorem lipsum dolor lorem lipsum dolorlorem lipsum dolor</label>
</dd>
```

**css**

```
#rr-element{width:180px; overflow:auto;}
dd label {float:right; width:150px; display:inline-block;}
dd label input {float:left; margin-right:10px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/T86h8/225/)

Answer (score 2):

```
#rr-element{
    width:180px; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The nowrap make in sort that the width is useless. I really need it to be inside a 180px width.

Comment: @Warface, you want hide overflowed label text?

Comment: @Warface, in this case, as you want to fit text?? Resize font??? I do not understand you...

Answer (score 0):

Change the Style

```
#rr-element{width:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
.rr-element{min-width:180px;}
dd input {
   margin-right:10px;
}

<dd class="rr-element">
<input value="2" id="rr-1" type="checkbox" name="SearchForm[position][]">
<label for="rr-1">Bartender</label>
</dd>
```

Comment: But now the label is outside the checkbox which make the label unclickable to check the box...

Comment: aaa, ok, then try and use nowrap

Comment: i updated my example, be arefull when setting the id and the for

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/219/ not working man... the text's still under the checkbox on line-break..

Comment: and also, rr-element is a class not a id

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/224/)

Code

```
<dd id="rr-element">
    <input value="2" id="rr-1" type="checkbox" name="SearchForm[position][]" />
<label for="rr-1">Value 1 lorem lipsum dolor lorem lipsum dolorlorem lipsum dolor</label>
</dd>
```

CSS

```
#rr-element{width:180px;}


label,
input {
    display: block;
}

input {
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

label {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can make two different div or span for them so equal space between your check box and text.

```
label
{
display:inline-block;
}
input[type=checkbox]
{
display:inline-block;
margin-right:10px;
}
```